# GSM device server communication

Tags: call, gsm, serial-communication, server-communication

What device what GSM modem do I need to communicate with the server to make call and what should such communication look like? I want to write a simple server in Go/C#, or it may be another language which, after receiving a command, should make a simultaneous call to a specific group of phone numbers and listen to the response from each number (accepted/declined), but it must be via a cellural network, not voip. External service providers are out.